# ajax call inside .each of another ajax call's success function - jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that returns data with a lat and long in it.

```
$.ajax(
{   
  url: 'json/data.json',
  dataType : 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: false,
  success: function(fullJSONData)
  {
    $(fullJSONData.events).each(function(index, oneJSONLine)
    {
        $('#eventList').append(newEvent(index, oneJSONLine))            
    });
  },
  error: function (e) 
  {
    console.log("error " + e.message);
  }

});
```

I am looping through using .each and here with the newEvent function I am calling another ajax request to reverse geocode the lat and the long.

```
function newEvent(iter, event)
{   
  var placeName

  getGeoCode(event.lat, event.long, function(returnAddress)
  {
    placeName = returnAddress
    //other processing
  }
}


function getGeoCode(lat, long, callback)
{
   var newurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
   newurl += lat
   newurl += ',' 
   newurl += long 
   newurl += '&key=AIzaSyCgISQV9F_6VW_wqyJk9rM5rTWvoD_eqVs'

$.ajax(
{
    //GeoCode Api       
    url: newurl,
    dataType : 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(fullJSONData)
    {
        callback(fullJSONData.results[0].formatted_address)     
    },
    error: function (e) 
    {
        console.log("error " + e.message);
    }

});
```

I think I understand what is happening but I am at a bit of a loss as to how to solve it.  I believe the .each is not waiting for the ajax inside it to complete as I would imagine would happen since it's ajax.  Can I force the .each to wait until each internal ajax call is completed before continuing?  I have tried `async:false` but I'm getting a deprication error saying that it is not good on the main thread.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I just about got the callback function working for the second ajax call, and have tried putting one around the first ajax call  but it's a little beyond me.

Thanks

Comment: You should use promises.  See http://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-10/advanced-promise-usage/

Answer (score 0):

A bug recently introduced in chrome 52 (august 2016) can also cause this kind of behavior. It prevents proper handling of ajax GET request initiated from the success handler.
Hoppefully, it will not last long.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=633696

Try to add cache:false to your ajax calls

Comment: Hi @Ludovic I'm not using Chrome but thanks for the info